# How to undo comment vote

Tags: support, comments, voting

When I inadvertently click to vote up a comment, I realise I cannot click to undo it. Is there a way to undo the comment vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to undo a comment vote. This feature has been [requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment), but currently the feature request is declined.

Comment: [:](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2626/how-to-undo-comment-vote/2627#2627)-) @Nhi

Comment: lol i was searching the wrong meta site.